# What does a concatenate operator do inside a INSTR function?

Tags: sql, string, plsql

What does a `||` operator do inside an `INSTR` function?

In the code below - I understand - `value1`,`~` will return the position for `~` in value1.(which will also be > 0

But I don't understand the use of `||` in the `INSTR`. Also how will it affect the return value for `INSTR`?

```
INSTR (value1,'~' || TO_CHAR (value2)|| '~') > 0
```

Comment: I am guessing that `value1` contains substrings delimited by `~` e.g. `~1~2~3~`

Comment: In my experience it's usually used when someone decided to put a 1:n relationship into a single column by storing multiple values separated by a `~` or `,`. It saves an additional table but costs performance, because you cannot use an index for that column. And cascade update/delete won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [double pipe operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) is used to do string concatenation in SQL and PL/SQL.

In your case it is used to build the lookup string from 3 parts: an initial ~, `value2` and a final ~.

For instance, if `value2` = 10, `INSTR (value1, '~' || TO_CHAR (value2)|| '~') > 0` will be expanded to `INSTR(value1, '~10~') > 0`